# why I get error Maven source deployment is not supported for Java 8 GAE project after migration from appcfg mvn to gcloud

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, gcloud, appcfg

i run this cmd

gcloud app deploy

and get this error

[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'gcloud' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/gallavie/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException

this is my plugin in pom.xml file

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                <webResources>
                    <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Could you share the entire command you are using and the full output from the command so we can check if there are any more relevant details to help you with the issue you are facing?

Comment: I updated my post thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting that error is because you are missing the `gcloud` dependency in your `pom.xml`, try adding the following to it:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
   <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.0</version>
</plugin>
```

Also for more information for deploy using maven to appengine, you can check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-maven)

Comment: Hi thank you fo replay I added this plug in and run the cmd gcloud app deploy and i get same error but when i run cmd mvn package appengine:deploy (cmd from documentation) so the deploy started but stoped because i get other error com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.2.0:deploy (default-cli) on project darimpo-test: App Engine application deployment failed: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.ProcessHandlerException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException

Answer (score 0):

had a similar issue after migration, pom was fine, the following command helped.

```
mvn clean package install -P dev appengine:deploy -Dapp.deploy.version=app_version
```

The documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/testing-and-deploying-your-app) were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The following has worked for me:

`mvn package appengine:deploy`

Answer (score 0):

Deployment from pure source via pom.xml is not possible with JAva runtimes using the legacy mode (so configured with appengine-web.xml)

So yes, the way to deploy such applications is to use mvn appengine:deploy by adding the appengine-maven-plugin.

Same for Gradle deployments.